# Image name with '#' sign using image_tag Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have an app that creates and prints Kanban cards for our production team. everything was working fine until on of the part numbers contained a '#' sign. I researched and found a couple of relevant posts stating everything after that sign wont go back to the server.

My issue is that the part numbers that contain the # sign, wont get queried correctly, hence the barcode image for that card will not display, here is my code:

```
<% if @card.area.name != "FG" %>
        <div style="text-align:center;"><%= image_tag "#{@card.part_no}" + "-" + "#{count}" + "-" + "#{@card.finish}" + "-" + "#{@card.card_index}" + ".png" %></div>
<% else %>
        <div style="text-align:center;"><%= image_tag "#{@card.part_no}" + "-" + "#{count}" + "-" + "#{@card.finish}" + ".png" %></div>
<% end %>
```

I'm new to Rails, and even newer to Javascript and the different libraries that are available.

Any direction on how I would get that `@card.part_no` value correctly with ajax or javascript?

Sorry if my post is not that clear, I appreciate your help.

Jaime.

Comment: You could prevously remove the `#` sign on your `@card.part_no`. 
`part = @card.part_no.gsub(/\#/, '')`.

Comment: Hi @MurifoX, thanks for your reply. The # sign is part of the number, which then queries the file for the .png file to display in the view. So how could I keep that # sign without the browser eliminating it and whatever comes after it? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my issue, was to encode the URL using the url_encode method, so that the browser didn't interpret the # sign as an anchor.

```
<div style="text-align:center;"><%= image_tag url_encode("#{@card.part_no}" + "-" + "#{count}" + "-" + "#{@card.finish}" + "-" + "#{@card.card_index}" + ".png") %></div>
```

This will take the following:

```
2134323#1-1-6-ASDS.png
```

And output:

```
2134323%231-1-6-ASDS.png
```

Hence, allowing the app to find the asset correctly.

I appreciate the help, and I hope this is useful to somebody else.

Jaime.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace #'s with a placeholder that you know will never be in a part number like & or ^ then on the server side move it back like so

```
$("card_from").submit( function() {
  card_no_element = $("card_no_input")
  var old_val = $(card_no_element).val();
  $(card_no_element).val(old_val.replace(/#/,"^"));
})
```

then probably in the model I would

```
Card << ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  before_save :replace_carrots_with_dollars

  def replace_carrots_with_dollars
    self.part_no.gsub!("^","#")
  end

end
```

Probably not the best solution ever but it should do the trick

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I'm new on javascript, and query, etc. I was reading about the :anchor symbol, and was wondering, if there is a way to use this instead?